# Desktop customization application

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, desktop, customization

Are you customizing your Mac desktop? If yes, do you use a 3rd party applications for that? I would like to know which applications you use.

Rule:

- One application per answer
- A link to the developer is necessary

Answer (score 2):

### [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool)

> GeekTool is a PrefPane (System Preferences module) for Mac OS 10.5. It let you display on your desktop different kind of informations, provided 3 default plugins :
>
> File plugin to monitor MacOS X activity with /var/log/system.log, or any file that you want to follow.Shell mode to launch custom scripts or commands like "df" to check space left on filesystems, "uptime" to monitor load of your machine... Finally, Image mode helps you monitor bandwith usage, CPU loads, memory availability of your server, via tools like MRTG

Answer (score 1):

### [DateLine](http://www.machinecodex.com/dateline/)

> DateLine displays a linear calendar on your Mac desktop which provides easy access to iCal and your events. The appearance of the DateLine is endlessly customizable and themeable.

Answer (score 0):

## [**CrystalClear Interface**](http://www.marsthemes.com/crystalclear/)

CrystalClear Interface is a gorgeous user interface for those who think completely different. It's for who wants to change the Mac theme, without needing to code, and you still can create your own theme.